# Run vsim from dmenu — it only works when directly invoked in the terminal

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, stdin

- Works: `vsim`, `sh -c vsim`
- Doesn't work: `echo "vsim" | sh`, `echo "vsim" | xargs -I {} sh -c "{}"`

I want to run ModelSim (`vsim`) with [`dmenu`](http://www.adercon.com/ac/node/25), which is triggered using `xbindkeys`.

---

#### Details

`vsim` is a executable for ModelSim, installed in `/opt/altera/modelsim_ase/bin`.

When I run it directly, it runs. But when I run it with `xargs` (eg. from dmenu), it does not work at all - the script itself launches, but probably in the wrong directory or something, I'm really clueless what's wrong.

My path (I added newlines for clarity):

```
[ondra@x201 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:
/usr/bin/site_perl:
/usr/bin/vendor_perl:
/usr/bin/core_perl:
/opt/altera/quartus/bin:
/opt/altera/modelsim_ase/bin:
/home/ondra/bin:
/home/ondra/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:
/opt/altera/University_Program/Monitor_Program/bin/bin
```

Where is `vsim`?

```
[ondra@x201 ~]$ which vsim
/opt/altera/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim
```

Run it with `xargs`:

```
[ondra@x201 ~]$ echo "vsim" |  xargs -I {} sh -c '{} &'
[ondra@x201 ~]$ Reading /opt/altera/modelsim_ase/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl 

# 10.1d

# 
# <EOF> 
^C
```

Run it directly:

```
[ondra@x201 ~]$ vsim
Reading /opt/altera/modelsim_ase/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl 
# --- and modelsim starts fine now ---
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: You cannot run `vsim` in this manner. It launches an interactive shell (written in TCL/Tk). What are you trying to do with this? You can find where `vsim` is located on disk like so: `type -f vsim`. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you ultimately trying to do with `vsim`. I worked w/ modemsim/modeltech for 15+ years, you're doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: @slm I have a dmenu-based launcher, and want to be able to run ModelSim with it. What'd you suggest? I'm not too excited with xterm floating around my workspace if I will never look at the outputs there (modelsim shows the errors in it's internal log window).

Comment: @slm output of `type -f vsim` is `vsim is /opt/altera/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim`. The only thing I want to do is to start modelsim, I think the vsim script does that - and it works when I just go to that folder and do `./vsim`. If there's another way, please share.

Comment: Can you not run `vsim` from any directory? The directory that includes `vsim` is in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @slm Indeed, I can. The problem is, it does not work with the xargs thing. This works: `sh -c "vsim"`, this does not: `echo "vsim" |  xargs -I {} sh -c "{}"`. So I concluded there's something rotten in the xargs syntax, but couldn't figure out what.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need `xargs`. That's for running multiple arguments against a particular command. You just want to launch `vsim` w/o having to keep the terminal around where you typed `vsim`, right?

Comment: I found that I should use xargs in some tutorial on dmenu, I suppose it may work without... There is really no terminal at all: I have a script (with dmenu) attached to a shortcut using `xbindkeys`. I press Meta-Space, type vsim, press return, and it should start modelsim.

Comment: Can you include this tutorial's URL so I may have a look?

Comment: Can't find it now, but basically it's the same like what this guy does -> https://bitbucket.org/dehun/xboomx/src/4b176141c7693406185f4541b987695ed3cd1116/xboomx/bin/xboomx?at=default

Not too important, I just tried and `dmenu_path | dmenu | sh` works with all but vsim (eg. I can run xcowsay with it)

Comment: Does demu launch `vim` in your scenario? The text editor `vim`, that isn't a typo 8-).

Comment: @slm yes, it's not too hapy about it though ("Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal"), but vim opens in the active terminal. I don't intend to run the dmenu command from a terminal though - but with xbindkeys. So vim would have no terminal to run in. It works eg with xcowsay or gedit, if you want some better example.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to see how demu reacted w/in the demu env. since it's similar to `vsim` in needing a terminal. I would wrap `vsim` similar to how you'd launch it from a graphical desktop such as GNOME, and then call the wrapper. I know engineers that would launch `vsim` in this manner. I don't have a working modelsim env. currently at home, so can't try this out to offer you better help than that. Good luck!

Comment: Also notable: vsim does not run when invoked in a shell script (I made a run_vsim.sh with "vsim" in it - got same error as above)

Comment: ok I'll try if that maybe works, add a shortcut with alacarte. I have a working quartus button made this way.

Comment: Yeah if `quartus` works I'd be surprised if `vsim` cannot work this way too. Quartus is also written in TCL/Tk, and has a similar structure with the console/command window typically in one of the pains like `vsim`.

Comment: If you're going to use dmenu, maybe look at the _dmenu_path_ and _dmenu_run_ scriptlets to see if how it launches stuff affects your use case?

Comment: @Amphiteóth dmenu_run works with "quartus", but "vsim" has the same problem as before. I'm actually not 100% sure "vsim" is the right script to run, but it works when I type it in terminal, so it should be.....

Answer (score 0):

From your experiments, it appears that the `vsim` program wants its standard input to be connected to a terminal; if it isn't, it either does nothing useful (because it's waiting for input but not getting any) or exits.

> ```
> $ vsim
> $ sh -c vsim
> ```

This runs the command normally from a terminal, in the foreground. The command can read input from the terminal.

> ```
> $ echo "vsim" | sh
> $ echo "vsim" | xargs -I {} sh -c "{}"
> ```

In both cases, the standard input of `vsim` is connected to the pipe from the `echo` command. The `vsim` command will see a pipe as its input and not a terminal, if it cares. And it will see the end of the file.

> ```
> $ echo "vsim" |  xargs -I {} sh -c '{} &'
> ```

Here, not only is `vsim`'s input connected to the pipe, but the process is executed in the background, so it can't read from the terminal at all (if it tries to, it'll be suspended until it gets foregrounded).

If you want to run `vsim` inside a pipeline where its standard input would not be connected to the terminal, redirect the input from the terminal to it.

```
echo "vsim </dev/tty" | sh
```

If you want to run the program from dmenu, you'll presumably have to open it in a new terminal emulator. Invoke `xterm -e vsim` instead of `vsim`.

I'm not familiar with vsim; it's quite possible that there are other ways of running it.